# how to add active class when we are navigating through router.navigate() in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular2-routing

how to adding active class based on route if I am navigating to other route using router.navigate()

template code

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
         <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of res " (click)="selected(item)">
               {{item.name}}
            <div> 
         <div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts file

```js
import {Router , ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

constructor(public router: Router, public route: ActivatedRoute,) { }
    
routingSelected(partnerCode) {
    this.router.navigate([partnerCode] , { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling routingSelected method in template?

Comment: @Chellappanவ I am routing based on code which coming from api response and based on i have to maped with code and than route so i can't route using routerLink in template.

Comment: So you mean partnerCode argument in routingSelected method coming from API response?

Comment: @Chellappanவ yes and based on that code i have object  { 'partnerCode':  routename }  routing to their respective route

Comment: use `<div routerLink=..>`: see the docs: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink and https://angular.io/guide/router -routerLink can be applied not only to an "a" else a div-

Comment: @Eliseo i have to navigate using router.navigate() so I can't navigate through <div routerLink=  ".."></div> with this .

Comment: "routerLink" is a directive that can applied also to a "<div>" -or to a "<p>", or to a "<li>" or...-. It's not necesary use in a "<a>" tag-. The directive not "navigate" itselft

Comment: @Eliseo you are right but in my case there are some logic after that success i have route otherwise I don't have to route  that logic I can't write in template file I have right in ts file only.

Comment: Well, you can use a `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` and `addClass` javascript (for me it's not the best option, but if only can change the .ts it's the only I can imagine

Comment: Does res array you interating in the tempate have partnerCode ?

Comment: yes @Chellappanவ but based on partnercode I have  object like { 'partnerCode1': 'route-A' , 'partnerCode2': 'route-B' } based on this object i am routing . so if in response partnerCode1 than i am routing to route-A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Workaround you can place template variable on router-outlet directive to get reference to ActivateRoute information. Then using ngClass you can add ngClass dynamically.

**component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div [ngClass]="{active:routerOutletVariable.isActivated && (routerOutletVariable.activatedRoute.url | async).
    some(cb(item.partnerCode))}" class="row" *ngFor="let item of res " (click)="selected(item)">
      {{item.name}}
      <div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <router-outlet #routerOutletVariable="outlet"></router-outlet>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
  cb = (partnerCode)=>{return (route)=>{
  return route.path === partnerCode;
  }}
```

Comment: getting this error  Cannot read property 'isActivated' of undefined

Comment: Have you placed template varible on router-outlet directive?

Comment: some issue with my end its working fine now thanks!!